# Adding to a Set in a conditional in Scala

Tags: scala, set, conditional-statements

I've written a visitor pattern and I'm matching an overridden subclass. I want to add the variable to the set value of the object and then return the modified object. How can I do that syntactically?

```
trait PropositionOrderer extends Visitor[Proposition]{
  var OurSet = SortedSet[Name] _
    override def variable = {
      _ match {
        case name => Variable(name)//SortedSet+(name).andThen(Variable(_))
      }
    }
}
```

Is there syntax to chain like a void function that adds to the `SortedSet` and then wait? I can't use `andThen` because I want to do two things, I want to add it to the `Set` and then I want to return the variable. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean something like this:

```
var ourSet = Set[String]()
def func(s: String) = 
  s match {
    case name =>        // a `case` can be followed by multiple statements 
      ourSet += name    // first we add `name` to the set
      name              // the last expression gets passed up to the assignment of x
  }
val x = func("test")
// ourSet is now Set("test")
// x is now "test"
```

A `match` expression will evaluate to the last expression of the matching `case`.  Here, the `case` that matches is `case name`.  The last expression under the `case name` block is `name`, so that's what the entire match evaluates to.  So the function `func` returns `name`, which is `"test"` when we call `func("test").  Thus,`x`is assigned to be`"test"`.

In addition, you can perform any other operations inside the `case` block you want.  Here, we are modifying `ourSet`.

Comment: Hell yeah, the syntax is still a bit confusing to me but you've helped me clean up HEAPS of my code.